# convert this multiple condition into ng-class conditional

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Hello there I need help in converting this 'if-else' with 'or' condition into conditon that can be used in ng-class.

This here is my ng-class with condition, but it's not working correctly.

```
<span ng-class="{'green': work > toWork,
                 'red': work < toWork,
                 'black': work == toWork || overall == '-'}">
    {{overall = showMonthly(work = (workers | getMonthValue: dts.value),
                            toWork = getMonthlyToWork(member.id, dts.value))}}
</span>
```

this is the condition I'd like to apply:

```
if (work > toWork) {
  return "green";
}else if (work < toWork) {
  return "red";
}else if (work == toWork || overall == "-") {
  return "black";
}
```

Comment: Explain the first argument to the `showMonthly` function. What is the expected result of `(workers | getMonthValue: dts.value)`? What is that expression doing?

Comment: There is something wrong with the conditions. When will the test `overall == "-"` ever be reached?

Comment: if the returned value is zero "0" the method will return "-"

Comment: In the pseudo code it tests `work==toWork`. In the HTML it tests `work==0`. Which is your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need ng-class for that, you just need to put the logic inside a method in your `$scope`, like below

```
$scope.getClass = function(work, toWork, overall){
    if (work == toWork || overall == "-"){
      return "black";
    }else if (work < toWork) {
      return "red";
    }else if(work > toWork)  {
      return "green";
    }
}
```

and in your view, call it like this

```
<span class="{{getClass(work, toWork, overall)}}"></span>
```

Comment: Updated the answer, now those will be available through arguments, try it

Comment: There is something wrong with the OPs conditions. When will the test `overall == "-"` ever be reached?

Comment: It should be in the if block not else if block

Answer (score 0):

```
<span ng-class="{'green': work > toWork,
                 'red': work < toWork,
                 'black': (work == toWork || overall == '-')}">
  ...
</span>
```

Check this. (*You have got a spell missing in your conditional statement*)

Happy coding!

Comment: its working but if the out put is "-" dash line, it's color is red and not black

Comment: It's because `work < toWork`, isn't it? There are some uncertainties in your markup, so why don't you make a quick sample on **Codepen** or **jsBin**, etc?